# Error: expected type-specifier before Class

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I am a java dev, learning c++. This following sample code doesn't compile and I couldn't find a clue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyObj {

  public:
  T value;
  MyObj(T a){
      this.value = a;
  }
}; 

template <class T>
inline MyObj<T> const& sum(MyObj<T> const& a, MyObj<T> const& b) 
{ 
    // append copy of passed element 
    T result = a.value+b.value;
    MyObj<T> obj = new MyObj(result);

    return obj;
}

int main() 
{ 
    try {
        MyObj<int> s1 = new MyObj(1);
        MyObj<int> s2 = new MyObj(3);

        MyObj<int> s3 = sum(s1,s2);

        cout << s3.value <<endl; 
    } 
    catch (exception const& ex) {
        cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() <<endl; 
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

It returns -

> main.cpp:31:29: error: expected type-specifier before ‘MyObj’
>            MyObj s1 = new MyObj(1);

and

> main.cpp:32:29: error: expected type-specifier before ‘MyObj’
>            MyObj s2 = new MyObj(3);

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `this->value = a;` or just `value = a;` in the constructor.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, as I have mentioned earlier, I am a java dev trying to learn c++. I am following net tutts.

Comment: And could anyone suggest why this question would be negatively marked ?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, I agree with you on learning from good books. But it's only natural for a new learner to ask silly questions even if he/she follows a good book. So throwing "haven't performed research" while not knowing the exact situation of someone or not even referencing a "good book" to the questioner when the questioner state is evident then it represents a demotivation or a raw pessimism.  Collective evolution doesn't happen by "down-voting" rather by helping mindset. Regards.

Comment: I upvoted. Post was helpfull for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `new` you are allocating memory on the heap, and so you need a pointer to point to that newly allocated memory: `MyObj<int>* s1 = new MyObj(1);`

Next, `MyObj` is a template class, so you have to specify `T` when you call the construtor: `MyObj<int>* s1 = new MyObj<int>(1);`

Because `s1`and `s2` are now pointers, `sum` can't accept them as pointers, you have deference them to get the values: `sum(*s1, *s2);`

As @rgettman  pointed out, `this` is a pointer, and so must be acessed using`->` and not `.`.